# KnockoutJS - Select next option in dropdown select box

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I have a dropdown list of sellers.  Currently, the first seller is selected.  When a button is clicked, it does some processing, then needs to automatically select the next seller in the list.  I found jQuery code that does this, but it is not updating the Knockout value.  I think that is because I am not using Knockout to change the selected value.

HTML:

```
<select data-bind="value: sellerID, options: $root.sellers, optionsValue: 'Value', optionsText: 'Text', optionsCaption: ' -- select a student --'" class="form-control" id="sellerSelect"></select>
```

ViewModel:

```
var SellerViewModel = function(groups) {
    var self = this;

    self.json = groups;
    self.groups = ko.computed(function() {
        var opts = [];
        for(var key in self.json)
        {
            if(self.json.hasOwnProperty(key))
            {
                opts.push({Text: self.json[key].majorGroup + " / " + self.json[key].minorGroup, Value: self.json[key].groupId});
            }
        }
        return opts;
    });

    self.roomID = ko.observable();
    self.roomID.subscribe(function(group) {
        if(group) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: '@Url.Action( "GetSellers", "Tally" )',
                data: { groupId: group, contractId: $("#contractId").val()  },
                success: function (data) {
                    var opts = [];
                    for (var key in data.sellers) {
                        if (data.sellers.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                            opts.push({Text: data.sellers[key], Value: key});
                        }
                    }
                    self.sellers(opts);
                    $("#sellerGroupId").val(group);
                }
            });
        }
    });

    self.sellers = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.hasSellers = ko.observable(false);
    self.sellerID = ko.observable();
    self.sellerID.subscribe(function(seller) {
        if(seller && verify == "True") {
            getVerifySeller(seller);
            easyGlanceModel.bigItemNo(null);
            easyGlanceModel.bigQty(null);
            tallyViewModel.highlightedRowIndex(null);
        }
    });

    self.phone = ko.observable();
    self.prize = ko.observable();
    self.firstName = ko.observable();
    self.lastName = ko.observable();
}
```

And this is the jquery I found to select the next option in a dropdown:

```
$('#sellerSelect option:selected').next().attr('selected', 'selected');
```

But I think that last line of JQuery needs to be Knockout instead.  But I don't know how or if is possible to do that in Knockout.  Either way, I need the sellerID to be updated with the new seller's ID.  Currently, it is always the first seller's ID.

**Update:**
Here is the returned JSON from GetSellers:

```
{"sellers":{"1492":"MORGAN R","1493":"LYDIA P","1494":"MADISON G","1495":"TREYTON T","1496":"ZACH D","1497":"CAMERON P","1498":"REGAN R","1499":"EVELYN B"}}
```

Comment: Just change the value of `sellerID`: find which element of `sellers` it matches, then set it to the one after that.

Answer (score 0):

can't you just set the selected item to the next one in the array on the click event. I put it in as an attribute but I'm sure you can get the next one in many ways.   run the snippet below. select a country click process. it will process that country and set the select to the next country.

```js
var Country = function(name, population, nextindex) {
  this.countryName = name;
  this.countryPopulation = population;
  this.nextindex = nextindex
};


function viewModel() {
  var self = this;
  this.availableCountries = ko.observableArray([
    new Country("UK", 65000000, 1),
    new Country("USA", 320000000, 2),
    new Country("Sweden", 29000000, 0)
  ]);

  this.selectedCountry = ko.observable('');
  this.click = function(value) {
    alert('you just processed ' + value.countryName)
    self.selectedCountry(self.availableCountries()[value.nextindex]);
  }

}


ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<p>
  Your country:
  <select data-bind="options: availableCountries,
                       optionsText: 'countryName',
                       value: selectedCountry,
                       optionsCaption: 'Choose...'"></select>
</p>

<div data-bind="with: selectedCountry">
  <!-- Appears when you select something -->
  You are processing <span data-bind="text: countryName"></span>.
  <button data-bind="click: $parent.click">Process</button>
```

Comment: This looks promising.  The only thing I am unsure about is the value of the select.  In your example it is a variable(selectedCountry) which is an observable.  In mine it looks like it is a string('Value') and not an observable.  So, for that one line of code where you wrote `self.selectedCountry(self.availableCountries()[value.nextindex]);`, I'm not sure what I should write.

Comment: I tried to write a solution in a comment however was getting a bit long.  do you have a small example for the JSON that ends up coming back in data or at least data.sellers in your ajax request?  (success: function (data))  if so could you add that to your original question. and I can try modifying my original answer to use your actual data.

Comment: Updated my original post with the JSON.

Comment: Ok I updated the answer here.  https://jsfiddle.net/cjg83dyv/1/.  I used your data to create options.  I created a writable computable in case you want to continue to use your selectedId outside of the selected object.